# Windows Scheduler Vs. Java TaskTimer

Tags: java, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

I have a .bat file in a Windows machine that starts our program by calling a main class of a Java executable(.Jar)

Now I need to run this every 30 mins.

I gone through several ways of doing it, but unable to decide which is better.

Scheduling through Windows scheduler or Using Java Timer. Which one to choose? 
I want only one instance of the process running. If the previous process doesnt complete within 30min, i could wait.

Please let me know what to go for, based on my use case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you referring to Java's *TimerTask*?

Comment: Ya i am referring to Java's TimerTask...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're better off using the Windows Scheduler. If there's a real risk of the process taking too long, you can create a file, or open a socket while the process is running and when another one tries to start up, it can detect that and simply quit. This would make it "miss" the 30m window (i.e. if the first job started at 12 and finished at 12:35, the next job would not start until 1).

But this way you don't have to worry at all about setting up long running processes, starting and stopping the java service, etc. The Windows scheduler just makes everything easier for something like this.

Comment: I tried doing this earlier, but i couldn't do following,
1) Scheduling the process to occur every 30min
2) Handling system reboot. Without user doing anything, scheduler should start every 30 min

Answer (score 0):

*TimerTask* is not a scheduling system, it is a library that provides tools for in-app scheduling. Seems that for your use-case you need a the system: you need it to run whether or not your app is running, you need reporting, etc. Windows Scheduler (or **cron** on unix/linux) is more appropriate for your needs.

Comment: But i couldnt find any option to set the process to be scheduled every 30min in windows scheduler. Where can i do that? Also i need to understand when to go for windows scheduler and when to use in-app scheduling?

Comment: Comparing TimerTask to a scheduling system is like comparing apples to fruit stores;-) 

TimerTask (and it's younger brother, ScheduledExecutorService) is a facility for programmers to use in their programs if they need scheduling. If you need to set up a system that schedules a specific task, you will need a system that does that - and provides, in addition to scheduling, task management, data persistence, high availability, reporting, etc. Of course, you could write such a system from scratch, and make use of TimerTask in it. But that's an overkill for your needs.

Comment: How to schedule a task in windows is totally off-topic for this site. You can find tutorials for this on the internet ([here's one](http://www.satsignal.eu/software/scheduled-tasks.html)).

Comment: I gone through the steps which is very clear. But here if previous process gone beyond 30min, i shouldnt start with new one. How can i handle this? Is there any other criteria that can be mentioned along with 30min interval...?

Comment: I think i can create a temp file along with .bat file, which i can check before i can start the next process. Is there any other better way?